# Spring @Async with App Engine?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, servlets

I am attempting to asynchronously call two separate servlets on App Engine using two `@Async` annotated methods.  The code running on App Enging IS NOT using Spring.  It's just using the normal Java Servlet API.  The code calling the servlets is using Spring.

The `@Async` on the calling methods does not seem to be working.  The methods are each called, and return in the normal order. (method->return, method->return)

I have `@Async` annotations on each public method.
I have the `@EnableAsync` annotation on the class calling the methods.
These are two separate classes.  No static classes involved.

I'm unsure if this is due to App Engine not supporting Servlet 3.0, or that I have not properly configured `@Async` propertly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post some configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

The issue was WHERE I was putting the **xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"** and  **task:annotation-driven** entries.

We have several XML files (that import other XML files) in our application.  Initially, I was putting these entries in the XML that contained the config for the bean containing the **@Async** annotation.  In order to get it to work, I had to put it in the **applicationContext.xml**

The calls are being made asynchronously on different threads and App Engine is handling them as such.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately GAE does not support Serlvet 3.0 spec as shown on [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091).You can apparently move to managed VMs and use it but sandbox GAE wont be using 3.0 for a while.

Comment: After further study, I don't believe App Engine is the problem.  I am attempting to send two calls from my server on two different threads.  App Engine should handle each separately (one not knowing about the other).  This is basically a "fire and forget" scenario.  At this point, I think it is still a configuration issue with @Async.